# Calibrated Monitor Messedup Results?

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, monitors

Alert : Novice Question !

I have calibrated my monitor with photoshop cs6 and was happy with it, but when i share results with other people, they are completely different on there mobile/laptops screens.

Please have a look at sample image to understand my problem.

I just want to give people results as i see it on my screen, but there is huge difference on both the screens.
Please tell me how to fix ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you calibrate your monitor?

Comment: I calibrated monitor with Photoshop by following this video on Youtube. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DStYd3bYXsY

Answer (score 2):

You may be right and it may be a display calibration issue, but my first reaction is that it looks like you are giving away images in AdobeRGB or ProPhotoRGB color space and they are viewed in non-color managed application. Before reviewing your calibration, make sure you save the images in sRGB. Also, when using color spaces, use "convert to" as opposed to "assign profile".

Comment: Hi MirekE, Thanks for reply...
First of all I would like to mention I have done calibration with help of this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DStYd3bYXsY ,  now coming back to point, Yes i was sharing results in AdobeRGB(1998) format, I have followed your instructions, converting to sRGB profile and saving the image for web, and again viewed on other device, but still both screens have totally different saturation and coloring.
Should i undo monitor calibration or something ?

Comment: Perhaps you could post one of your images and somebody here could tell you how it looks on their screen. You could also download some of the testing images and see if they look correct or over/under saturated on your screen. And yes, you could do a new calibration or use the default profile...  http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/downloadable_1/DL_page.html

Comment: I just watched the video. Yes, I would undo this...